# System backup with Norton Ghost

Tags: windows-vista, backup, external-hard-drive, restore, norton-ghost

I will upgrade my system from Windows Vista Home Premium (x64) to Windows 7 (x64). Before starting the upgrade process, I want to back up my current system with Norton Ghost. I have never used it before, so I need assistance to do that. At the moment, there is 139 GB used space by Vista and I have 1 TB external HD connected via USB. If you can tell me the step by step instructions about how to back up and how to restore if the upgrade somehow fails, I'll appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Radified](http://ghost.radified.com/)**, the best guide to Norton Ghost i have ever come accross.

It presents what many consider the ultimate back-up strategy. It is based on features found in Norton Ghost, a hard drive imaging/cloning software program developed by Symantec.

Although designed around Norton Ghost (considered the most reliable application of its kind), the strategies presented can be applied to *any* disk cloning program.

Answer (score 1):

it's easy.

- Open ghost with usb support > select "Image From Partition / İmage From Disk"
- select the partition which you have Vista installed.
- Then it will ask you to save your ghost image > Select your 1 TB USB disk.
- Then wait for the process.

Comment: i suggest NOT to recommend pirated software here. many of the tools on Hiren's Boot CD (incl. Ghost) are commercial applications that have not been legally licensed for redistribution.

Comment: ha ha ha proove that it is illegal then...
He can also run Norton Ghost legally.Hiren Boot CD is an alternative solution..!